# Compare two dates with different formats in Python

Tags: python, django

I'm not familiar with Python, just debugging an existing code. I'm comparing two dates here but they have different formats. I get the "TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes" when I do the compare.

> `if date_start <= current_date:`
>
> "TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware
>
> `str(date_start)` >> 2015-08-24 16:25:00+00:00
>
> `str(current_date)` >> 2015-08-24 17:58:42.092391

How do I make a valid date comparison? I'm assuming I need to convert one to another format.

**UPDATE**

```
hour_offset = 0
minute_offset = 0
if timezone_offset:
    offset_sign = int('%s1' % timezone_offset[0])
    hour_offset = offset_sign * int(timezone_offset[1:3])
    minute_offset = offset_sign * int(timezone_offset[3:5])    
    current_date = (datetime.datetime.now() + 
        datetime.timedelta(hours=hour_offset,minutes=minute_offset))
```

The previous dev might have applied the timezone offset this way. Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457452/comparing-dates-and-times-in-different-formats-using-python

Comment: There is no code to debug here

Comment: sorry, let me modify the question and add additional code..

Comment: Are the two date-times from the same location? If not, there's no sensible way to compare offset-naive date-times with offset-aware ones.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Let me show you the code on how the current_date was derived. I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more details here to solve.But if you want to get a `offset-naive` time.Try this

```
(offset-aware-datetime).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

To add a timezone to `offset-naive` time.Try this

```
(offset-naive-datetime).replace(tzinfo=tz)
```

Comment: That will fail if the timezone isn't utc - since you'll change the time on the timedate.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder I agree with you. I'm currently trying different time zones.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder updated the answer(copied from you :p)

Answer (score 2):

Use `dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)` to add a timezone to the naive datetime, so that they can be compared.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert the date to seconds since epoch and then compare. Say,if your date is `2015-08-24 16:25:00` then you can convert to seconds using datetime method. It takes parameters as `(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[,second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])`. It returns a datetime object. Finally, you can use strftime() to get seconds as a zero-padded decimal number. So your code can be:

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime(2015,8,24,16,25,0)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2015,8,24,17,58,42,92391)
if int(d1.strftime("%s")) > int(d2.strftime("%s")):
    print "First one is bigger"
else:
    print "Second one is bigger"
```

I hope this helps!